# mysql union all with aliases, syntax error

Tags: mysql, union

Why do I get

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'as q2)' at line 7
```

with

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE q1.d1, q1.a, q2.b, (q1.a-q2.b)/q1.a*100 as Percentage
FROM 
  (SELECT Date(date) d1, count(id_update) a 
   FROM vas_updates 
   WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
   GROUP BY DATE(date)) as q1
UNION ALL
  (SELECT date(date) as d2, count(id_update) as b 
  FROM vas_updates 
  WHERE date BETWEEN
    date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) 
    AND
    date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) group by DATE(d2)  ) as q2
```

Can't I use aliases with UNION?

UPDATE:
this query might have leftovers from another query, I was tyring to understand the syntax error first.

What I'm trying to calculate is the percentage increase or decrease of two sums which are the hits from the last 2 hours of today compared to same timeframe from yesterday.

the table has just `id` and `datetime`

Comment: If you had proper formatting/indenting in there, you'd see that the `)` before `as q2` is dangling and has no matching `(`.

Comment: It gives me the same error if removed :|

Comment: The error message seems to be for something different from what you posted, since there's no `)` after `as q2`, and it's not on line 7.

Comment: there's also the meta problem of your initial `select` only applying to your `select Date(date)` inner query, and not both of the union'd. query

Comment: You seem to be confusing a UNION and a JOIN. With a UNION you do not need to alias the sub queries

Comment: And with a union you can't reference columns in each subquery in the main `SELECT` clause.

Comment: How do I calculate "percentage" without using aliases? And yes I need UNION (no matches to JOIN the two selects).

Comment: What are you trying to calculate the percentage of? If you can't relate the two subqueries, how do you pair up `q1.a` with `q2.b`?

Comment: When you make a union, the column aliases all come from the first subquery. There is no `q2.b` in the result of the union.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post with more info.

Comment: @SandroAntonucci see if my answer clarifies you

Comment: Looking at your updated question, it IS a JOIN you want, not a UNION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you actually want a JOIN

Something like this:-

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE q1.d1, q1.a, q2.b, (q1.a-q2.b)/q1.a*100 as Percentage
FROM 
(
    SELECT Date(date) d1, count(id_update) a 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
    GROUP BY DATE(date)
) as q1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date(date) as d2, count(id_update) as b 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date BETWEEN date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) AND   date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
    group by DATE(d2)  
) as q2
ON q1.d1 = q2.d2
```

EDIT

Checked your updated query and it IS a JOIN you need.

You can use a CROSS JOIN. You are returning 1 value from each sub query, and doing a calculation on those values:-

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE q1.d1, q1.a, q2.b, (q1.a-q2.b)/q1.a*100 as Percentage
FROM 
(
    SELECT MIN(Date(date)) d1, count(id_update) a 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)
) as q1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(Date(date)) d2, count(id_update) as b 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date BETWEEN
    date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) 
    AND
    date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
) as q2
```

CROSS JOIN gives you every combination of the rows. In this case you have 1 resulting record. I have just returned the MIN date to get a single date to display.

Comment: See updated solution to give you the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

You Can't. A UNION operation does not allow you to use alias on subqueries as it is an operation that creates a single table.

Like this:

```
select 1 a, 2 b 
union all
select 3 blah, 4 bleh
```

This will result in

```
a     b
1     2
3     4
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68b32/444

On this query you only have two fields no matters what is on the second query it will only parse the first one, check if the others querys has the same quantity of fields as the first and if they are of the same type. Name the UNIONed querys with alies is invalid.

So I think what you need is probably a JOIN OR just all the fields

So, your query would be something like:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE tbl.d1, 
                    tbl.a, 
                    tbl.b, 
                    (tbl.a-tbl.b)/tbl.a*100 as Percentage
  FROM  (SELECT Date(date) d1, 
                count(id_update) a,
                null d2,
                null b 
           FROM vas_updates 
          WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT null d1, 
                null a
                date(date) as d2, 
                count(id_update) as b 
           FROM vas_updates 
          WHERE date 
            BETWEEN date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) 
                AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) group by DATE(d2)
         ) tbl
```

But this most likely will not make the calculations right. You can use the version that @Kickstart has provided you.

**Query of the answer from @Kickstart**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE q1.d1, q1.a, q2.b, (q1.a-q2.b)/q1.a*100 as Percentage
FROM 
(
    SELECT Date(date) d1, count(id_update) a 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
    GROUP BY DATE(date)
) as q1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT date(date) as d2, count(id_update) as b 
    FROM vas_updates 
    WHERE date BETWEEN date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
    group by DATE(d2)  
) as q2
ON q1.d1 = q2.d2
```

I decided to put this answer to explain **why** you are using the UNION operation in a wrong way.

Comment: I got it BUT if you use JOIN, that ON will never work because the date (d1 and d2) will never match since the sums come from two different dates.

Comment: So, create some data rows as an example and put it on a http://sqlfiddle.com and show what would be your desired result. It will be much more easy to find a solution to you. Doesn't need to be your entire data, few rows would do fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that @Kickstart is right,and  you can try this.

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE d, a
FROM 
  (SELECT Date(date) d, count(id_update) as a 
   FROM vas_updates 
   WHERE date > date_senter code hereub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
   GROUP BY DATE(date)) 
UNION ALL
  (SELECT date(date) as d, count(id_update) as a 
  FROM vas_updates 
  WHERE date BETWEEN
    date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) 
    AND
    date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) group by DATE(d2)  )
```

I'm wrong,UPDATE, you can try like this

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE q1.d1, q1.a, q2.b, (q1.a-q2.b)/q1.a*100 as Percentage
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(Date(date),'%H')  as d1, count(id_update) a 
        FROM vas_updates 
        WHERE date > date_sub(now(), interval 2 hour)  
        GROUP BY DATE(date)
    ) as q1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(Date(date),'%H')    as d2, count(id_update) as b 
        FROM vas_updates 
        WHERE date BETWEEN date_sub(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), interval 2 hour) AND date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) 
        group by DATE(d2)  
    ) as q2
    ON q1.d1 = q2.d2
```

Comment: If you think that an answer is right, you should upvote it and not provide the same answer (with few modifications). Or at least present something new.